# One Image to be image source of all buttons and windows icons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using WPF! I have created an interface in which user can select any image and save it in database, then this saved image assigned to be as buttons Image Source or a icon and similarly to all other Navigation Panel items, etc.

My query is that i have to retrieve image every time from database, Is there any other possibility to save image without connectivity to database i mean Application Settings ?

Comment: are you serializing the whole image to database or saving just paths?

Comment: yes i want this-- @nit